# Remove "/web" in subfolder in shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, symfony

I have a subfolder on my domain which contains a sf2 application. The actual url to access the app is like that: **www.mydomain.com/subfolder/web**

I want to properly remove the "/web" from the url.

I tried to do that with this htaccess in my subfoler :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

to redirect requests in web directory

But it gives me a 404 when i want to go on the home url with this message :
**"No route found for 'GET /subfolder/'"**

I know I miss something but I really don't know what and im really not an expert in htaccess

PS : It's impossible to create a VirtualHost to solve the problem because i am on a shared hosting

Answer (score 1):

I use symbolic links.

From webroot:
`ln -s  subfolder/web newfolder`

Answer (score 0):

Check out RewriteRule's documentation
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

The first parameter that you are passing is the pattern it is matching

You are essentially matching any directory inside of subfolder and redirecting it to
web/

I think what you want is something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! ^subfolder/web.
RewriteRule ^subfolder(.*)$ subfolder/web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

So what I think this does is the following:

- While the request is not a file and is not subfolder/web or subfolder/web/
- Rewrite the url from subfolder(.*)$ to subfolder/web/$1

Comment: You are right and wrong..."The first parameter that you are passing is the pattern it is matching" this is true. So if he wants to not display the `web` folder, then it should match the pattern without the `web` folder and rewrite to it.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about the question then.
Isn't he trying to remove the /web(.*)$ portion of the url and redirect the matched portion back to the /subfolder directory or is it the other way around?

Comment: To my understanding, he has a sub folder containing his Symfony application and he wants people who hit `http://website.com/subfolder` to be displayed the content of `http://website.com/subfolder/web`

Comment: You're right cheesemacfly, but how can i do that ? I already tried to establish a symlink but it didn't seem to work too.

Comment: I've updated the example since I think I understand the problem better now.

Comment: Finally i just opted for a redirection from http://website.com/subfolder/ to http://website.com/subfolder/web. It's more simple and i havn't any SEO obligation, so /web at the end isn't really a problem.